# ffmpeg hardcode subs on flv

Tags: centos, ffmpeg, video-subtitles

Giving up on trying to use `videosub.js`, I am now trying to hard code subtitles to the video file using `ffmpeg`.

Have run into trouble with configuration files not found, when trying to hard code the `srt` type of subtitle on `flv` type of video file.I decided to convert the `srt` file to an `ass` type subtitle but that didn't work either.

Now I am wondering, if it is because you can't do it with an `flv` type video or I need to go back to fixing the error I'm getting when trying to run the command. I am using Linux `CentOS 6.4` using latest static release of `ffmpeg` for 32bit. 
That being :

> `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file`

This is what I see in `ffmpeg` static folder:

```
-bash-4.1# cd ffmpeg-static
-bash-4.1# 
-bash-4.1# ls
32bit
-bash-4.1# cd 32bit
-bash-4.1# ls
var
-bash-4.1# cd var
-bash-4.1# ls
cache
-bash-4.1# cd cache
-bash-4.1# ls
fontconfig
-bash-4.1# cd fontconfig
-bash-4.1# ls
3830d5c3ddfd5cd38a049b759396e72e-.cache-3  CACHEDIR.TAG
```

I have since noticed besides the ffmpeg script residing in /usr/bin there is only one other folder at root being the listed one above with only the cache so obviously I have missed many added installs because also I have no fplayer.

Comment: Do not hardcode ever.